# Check if exist in array (all in foreach)

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

I need to check every row in another array, and if exist - do something.

This is my code:

```
<?php $Sekcje = explode( ',', $Detail->SectionsPrefered ); ?>
     <?php foreach ($SectionsList as $SectionOption): ?>
           <div class="checkbox">
           <?php if ( in_array( $SectionOption->Title , $Sekcje ) ): ?>
                 *
           <?php endif ?>
               <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $SectionOption->Title; ?>">
                  <?php echo $SectionOption->Title; ?>
               </label>
           </div>
     <?php endforeach ?>
```

It's display only one '*', but must display for 3 rows (Section1, Section2, Section3)

Here var_dumps:

**$Sekcje**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "Section1"
  [1]=>
  string(9) " Section2"
  [2]=>
  string(9) " Section3"
}
```

**$SectionsList**

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#33 (3) {
    ["ID"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Title"]=>
    string(8) "Section1"
    ["Description"]=>
    string(13) "Opis sekcji 1"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#34 (3) {
    ["ID"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["Title"]=>
    string(8) "Section2"
    ["Description"]=>
    string(13) "Opis sekcji 2"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#35 (3) {
    ["ID"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["Title"]=>
    string(8) "Section3"
    ["Description"]=>
    string(13) "Opis sekcji 3"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#36 (3) {
    ["ID"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["Title"]=>
    string(8) "Section4"
    ["Description"]=>
    string(13) "Opis sekcji 4"
  }
  [4]=>
  object(stdClass)#37 (3) {
    ["ID"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["Title"]=>
    string(8) "Section5"
    ["Description"]=>
    string(13) "Opis sekcji 5"
  }
}
```

Comment: ` Section2` != `Section2`. See the `9` and the `8`? https://eval.in/483901 https://eval.in/483900

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in_array()` does exact(ish) string matches, and your strings are different. From your own dumps:

```
string(9) " Section2"
string(8) "Section2"
```

Note the extra space in your `$Sekcje`

Answer (score 0):

As MarcB pointed out, you have spaces in your values caused by the `explode()`.  Instead of using `explode()`, use:

```
preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', $Detail->SectionsPrefered, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
```

This will avoid having blank spaces around the array values.